# How to stop a value from a Cloud Firestore database to be printed multiple times?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an activity which hosts a fragment. In the fragment I have a method which helps me get the data from the database like this:

```
public void readData(ListCallback listCallback) {
    DocumentReference listIdRef = rootRef.collection("lists").document(listId);
    listIdRef.addSnapshotListener((snapshot, e) -> {
        if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
            ListModel listModel = snapshot.toObject(ListModel.class);
            String direction = listModel.getDirection();
            Log.d("TAG", direction);
        }
    });
}
```

When I start the activity for the first time, everything works fine, the value of the `direction` field is printed in the logcat **once**. If the value of the `direction` is changed, the `onEvent()` method is triggered and the value of `direction` field is printed in the logcat again. When I leave the activity and I come back, for the first time the value of the `direction` is printed but if the value of the `direction` is changed, instead of printing the value once is printed twice. If I leave the activity and I come back to do the same thing again, the value is printed three times. How can I stop this from happening? I need to be printed only once each time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `direction` and when/why is it being changed?

Comment: Are you removing the listener when you pause your activity? Without more code I can only assume you are just adding the listener over and over but never removing it

Comment: @GhostDerfel I'm using `firestoreRecyclerAdapter.startListening();` in `onStart()` method and `firestoreRecyclerAdapter.stopListening()` in `onStop()`. Do I need something more?

Comment: @MikeSpeed `direction` is a field which is a String and can have different values. That's why is changing.

Comment: @IoanaP.check the SnapshotListener documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener you should remove the listener if you don't need it anymore or simply check if there is already a listener registered for your activity

Comment: @GhostDerfel I have added `ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {});` and added `registration.remove();` in the `onStop()` method, but still the same issue.

Comment: I don't have a clear scope of your code but I think the best place to put those would be under onResume and onPause since onStop might never be called depending on how you declared your activity, you can also try to hold a reference to your listener and double check if there is one before adding it

Comment: @GhostDerfel Man, you were right. Removing the listener in `onStop()` and double check if there is a `registration` active before adding it, solved my problem. Please provide an answer for this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on the comment section the issue was related to adding the listener but never removing it, which caused the activity to keep adding new listeners without removing the previous one (that's the reason for the multiple calls).

The solution for this error is to simply remove the listener or to check if the listener is already attached to our instance.

**To better understand the listener life cycle and how to handle this cases I recommend checking the following link:**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Comment: You're awesome! Thank you!